# What if I think a deleted answer is worthwhile?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

If someone deletes their answer because they think it's unhelpful, but I (as the question owner or interested party) believe it does add something, what is the right thing to do?

Comment: Vote to undelete it?

Comment: I don't see that option.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That would only be appropriate if it was something like a ragequit, where they were intentionally removing content the owner knew was good content.  If someone else knows that their own answer is wrong, undeleting it is not appropriate; you're now preventing them from correcting their own error.

Comment: @Servy, yes, I assumed that's the case since the questioner says they *believe it does add something*. Also, the vote is non-binding as usual, so some kind of consensus will be required for the answer to actually be undeleted.

Comment: Maybe leave a comment on the question referencing what part of the deleted question was useful?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If I post an answer, realize it's wrong, and you come along and see it without realizing why it doesn't work/is problematic/etc. then I don't want you undeleting the answer just because you haven't figured out why my answer is harmful, nor am I likely to edit/comment on the *deleted* answer to explain to 10k users why it's wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Boy Just to clarify. I deleted my answer, since rodrigo's answer is much better than my proposal was. (I guess you were referring to your recent question).

Comment: @Servy, you have a point. It may not be possible to differentiate between a ragequit and a deleted "bad" answer. Doing nothing may be the best option.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sure, but it got me thinking - there may be times where you think your answer is not the best, but it still adds value. When I accept an answer, we don't delete all the other ones for being worse

Comment: @Mr.Boy Non-accepted answers can add value, but when even the author realizes themselves that their answer is adding no value then that's different.

Comment: @Mr.Boy You'll begin seeing "undelete" on those deleted answers after you reach 20k.

Comment: @Servy: _"or am I likely to edit/comment on the deleted answer to explain to 10k users why it's wrong"_ Well, that's the problem. Write a comment on it before you delete it; problem solved. Why would you not do that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because they wouldn't imagine 3 20k users trying to bring back a harmful answer, and assume that they know better.

Comment: @Servy: So they're just assuming they're right in their judgement of the post, and that there's no chance whatsoever they're mistaken and that their SO expert friends may have dissenting opinions that might be useful/interesting as to the value of the material? Nice!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If someone else really feels that the answer is valuable, they can re-post it in their own name, rather than forcing someone who feels that it's not a helpful answer to have it posted under their name.

Comment: @Servy: That really sounds like a backwards way to go about things. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And yet 32 people have upvoted the answer advocating it, and not *one person* has downvoted it.

Comment: @Servy: And yet more people upvoted Frederic's "vote to undelete it?" simple-solution comment than upvoted the actual question. I think what you'll find is really going on is that people are ignoring this silliness! Also, it's meta. Also, appeal to popularity is vacuous.

Comment: I have now written a nice new answer for you to downvote. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You think that 25 is greater than 32?  You're sure about that?

Comment: @Servy: No, it obviously isn't (and the fact that someone upvoted your nonsense strawman argument is a testament to the folly of meta voting). Read my comment more carefully.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could create a community wiki answer, using the content of the previous answer and referencing to that currently deleted post.

In that way you take control over the answer, comply to the license by attributing. Also by making it a community wiki, other users don't think you want to have easy reputation.

Maybe you should add why you think it is a valid / useful answer.

Comment: What happens if the answer posted contain some sort of copyrighted proprietary code, and the user deleted it because he discovered that?

Comment: That is a valid point, but when he posts he effectively states it is a work that is allowed to be published under the CC-by-SA license of the site. That would be a hard case and certainly you don't want to expose the copyrighted material again. I would suggest to flag the original answer and ask to destroy it.

Comment: I disagree defacing your deleted answer, but in this case it seems reasonable to replace the answer by a 'deleted for copyright reasons' notice.

Comment: @Malavos: Then that's their problem - or SE's should the copyright holder decide to pursue it.

Comment: If I have no control over my content I would be hesitant to provide it.

Comment: Then don't post on SO. By definition you lose control over your content. You license it under another license, granting people to use it.

Comment: Guys, please read my example properly. The person did not know that such code was stolen from a copyrighted source. He posted it in so, removed because the owner of the content asked him to, then, SO vote to undelete it.
That would be, at least, problematic.

Comment: If it isn't your own code never post it.

Comment: @Malavos We do not delete copyright content without a valid DMCA filing from the copyright holder. So the problem here is that the copyright holder simply contacted the answer poster, rather than using the proper DMCA mechanism. We _do_ delete content when we receive a valid DMCA filing. See "Copyright Policy": http://stackexchange.com/legal#15CopyrightPolicy

Comment: This is a completely backwards approach. Taking someone's content and reposting it "against their will" is (a) just the same as undeleting their content against their will, but without the consensus element that undeletion votes provides, (b) added noise for no particular gain.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You making the same mistake as someone else is quite different from preventing them from fixing their own mistake, and also forcing them to accept the consequences (i.e. downvotes) for that mistake instead of you.

Comment: This seems a bit of an edge case. If the original answer author states they deleted it due to copyright/license infringement that's one thing, but if they don't we don't really know this and it would rely on someone flagging the CW answer as normal?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young it was just a example - I did not make any statements that you do not delete it. You do know that by Brazilian law, for instance, a person is responsible for such post, not SO, so, say Forte's lawyers would go after that guy, not SO. That guy would answer removing the answer, and according to your comment, as I understood it, folks will vote to undelete it, and SO will only in fact delete it if the DMCA arrives to them. But it will never arrive to SO, and the user will keep "reposting" the in case content. He could get a sentence that could reach up to 4 years in the cubes.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young [here's a source for my comment.](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/L9610.htm). Do you see my point? I'm not blaming SO though, but it would happen.

Answer (score 10):

I agree that simply undeleting an answer because you don't see why it was deleted, would not be good. It was deleted for a reason after all.

So my solution would be to have the ability to add comments to deleted answers, in order to ask the deletee why they deleted it. That way at least you can reach an understanding why it was harmful (or useless or whatever).

Answer (score 7):

### Vote to undelete it.

When someone posts on Stack Exchange they give the community a non-trivial amount of control over that content. As a courtesy, we tend not to go overboard with this — for example, it is generally accepted etiquette not to re-apply an edit that the original author reverts — but it is only that: a courtesy.

In the case of wanton content destruction, when an author is deleting / has deleted their answer, the following should happen:

1. **The author should leave a comment or note on the content**, explaining why they are deleting it. This removes all doubt as to intentions, and gives 10k+ users a basis on which to disagree if indeed they do.

   Say, the author has decided that one of their facts is wrong when, in fact, everyone else reckons they were probably right the first time — if the content simply disappears without an explanation, it is not clear what is going on and that a discussion could be had. It is polite to let everyone know why you thought your post should be deleted.
2. If the deleted post was vandalised, the **vandalism should be reverted**.

   Sorry, I don't really care whether you're embarrassed by your mistake (and perhaps this'll encourage you to think a little more before writing your next post!). When a post is "deleted", it's not *really* deleted: it is simply hidden from low-rep users. It is completely reasonable for 10k+ users to want to know what content has been deleted — if for no other reason than they may wish to exercise their undelete votes! though simply being able to see the history of the Q&A is enough reason, as that is the entire purpose of the 10k+ privilege to see "deleted" content; it's not an author's job to undo that right — and self-vandalism out of shame prevents anyone from taking any further actions whatsoever.

   Of course, we cannot fix this if the vandalism occurred within the post's original grace period.
3. If indeed some people think the content was fine as it was, just as one might improve Q&A by editing its content, **one should vote to undelete good content**.

   This is effectively equivalent to either reposting the original content or writing an answer with the same general idea yourself in the first place. It is a move to [re-]add what you feel is good content to the site.

   The benefit of undelete-voting over reposting is that reposting duplicates is noisy, and it just seems to violate that earlier notion of etiquette to repost someone's content without *at least* a community vote.

The feature that Stack Exchange provides to cover the case in which you think a deleted answer is worthwhile, *is* the "undelete" vote button. That is its purpose. Therefore it appears entirely self-evident to me that any other response is a violation of the model.

Comment: You consider deleting an answer that you know to be wrong/unhelpful to be *vandalism*?  If so, then why is there an option to delete one's posts in the first place?  Vandalism would be deleting one's posts *that they know to be helpful, out of spite*, which is quite different.

Comment: @Servy: I assume LRiO is referring to *wiping the post's contents before deleting*, the usual meaning when referring to self-vandalism, especially in the case of self-deleted posts.

Comment: @Servy: No, I consider vandalising an answer to be vandalism. Just as everybody else does. That is, when its contents are replaced via edit with "adsiughaskduygaskudygfaskduyfga".

Comment: Voting to undelete does very little unless others join in, and they are not likely motivated to do so in most cases