# Should we give <10k users the content of a deleted answer when they ask for it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, etiquette

Context: [Answer got deleted. Is it possible to retrieve it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340943/answer-got-deleted-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-it)

I posted the content of the answer, along with this intro:

> I don't know if we should give low-rep people access to deleted
>   answers like this, but there's precedent
>   [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130056/useful-answer-to-my-question-deleted).
>   If the powers-that-be consider this unintended use of this
>   functionality, I'll happily delete it.
>
> Note that the answer might contain errors which caused the poster to
>   delete it.

Quickly got some downvotes and a comment advising against doing this, so deleted the answer. Consensus at [What if I think a deleted answer is worthwhile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309454/what-if-i-think-a-deleted-answer-is-worthwhile) seems to be that it's fine to repost a deleted answer as a Community Wiki, or to vote-to-undelete on the answer, when it's a (possibly) useful answer. So I *think* that my action was OK, but I'd rather have some official stance on this.

Comment: Voting to undelete is a bit different, as it requires at least some semblance of consensus. A 10k+ user copy-pasting the answer on Meta is a unilateral decision.

Comment: You didn't have a good reason to post that content. You don't know if it is useful. Even if it is, you are posting it on Meta; not on the main site. How is that going to be useful for the community?

Comment: @CodyGray Reposting a deleted answer as CW is also an unilateral decision, but that seems to be OK though?

Comment: @ayhan OK, perhaps I should have reposted on the SO question instead of the MSO question. The question remains the same though: should we do this on request of <10k users?

Comment: The linked question makes it clear that there was a good reason to post the content and that it was useful. The linked question being on meta is the reason it's on meta @ayhan.

Comment: Posting a CW answer is just bypassing the undelete vote requirements. I don't agree with that. If *you* think it is useful, I think you should vote to undelete. @Ben The only reason that provides is "because somebody asked for it". If that's a good enough reason, why hide deleted answers at all?

Comment: Copying the content of a deleted answer to Meta is not the same as undeleting an answer on Main. Undeleting on Main is an edge case covered by SO's guidelines. Copying deleted content from Main and pasting it elsewhere is a violation of the trust OP puts in SO.

Comment: Don't copy deleted content, and don't undelete it. If you _must_, provide a screenshot in a link, but don't mess with the original deletion.