# Notification about undeletion of answer

Tags: support, feature-request

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767790/c-less-operator-uses-casting-operator/43767961) question. It already had an answer from BoundaryImposition but that answer had a comment asking for a more thorough answer.

At that point I decided to write an answer myself pointing out the things that that answer missed. Right as I submit my answer the other answer is edited and the missing information is added, rendering my answer useless.

So I proceeded to delete my answer only to get reputation notifications from that answer 10 minutes later. It appears that my answer was undeleted (probably by other community members) but I don't have any traceback on this. Maybe my "delete answer" request was never honored, maybe the Stack Overflow unicorn revived it, I don't know.

Is it true that the author of an answer that gets undeleted by the community is not notified? And if so, why?

Comment: Yes, [other members of the community undeleted your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43767961/timeline). As far as I'm aware, there is no notification for this, although I couldn't find any particular reason why this is the case. (you can view the timeline for your post by going to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/POST_ID/timeline — the first number in the 'share' link is your post ID)

Comment: I would expect, that I can delete **my answer**, especially if it has no comments and nobody should revive it..

Comment: @Rekshino It's not **your** answer though. You've given the ability to share and modify it under the [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: Hmm.. again I haven't seen the small print.. :) My answer is not my answer, further logic: my reputation is not my reputation(so, if 95% from answer will be edited;) ) and I do not belong to myself. :)

Comment: Your answer is really only your answer in a limited way.  Generally though one should not undelete something the author felt like deleting.  See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309454/what-if-i-think-a-deleted-answer-is-worthwhile

Comment: @NathanOliver: See my answer on that very page. I don't understand the problem with any of this, I really don't.

Comment: This was clearly not a rage-quit deletion.  You can't reasonably force anybody to maintain an answer if they opt out of doing so immediately.  Honor the poster's intention first, it is the nice thing to do.  Prime directive applies.

Comment: @HansPassant: No, it doesn't. The terms of the licence do. The community is given a vote, and the community used that power. If you think we shouldn't be able to do so, that's a feature request. Undeletion is not reserved for undoing "rage-quit deletions" and I don't know where you read that it is.

Comment: Hmm, that must be the kind of reasoning that makes lawyers so popular.  It is the *prime* directive, there is no superlative.  Be nice, please.   Or at least allow me to disagree with you, it will probably happen again :)

Comment: Is this a [meta-tag:bug] report then or a [meta-tag:feature-request]? Must be one or the other surely... O_o

Comment: @HansPassant: I was nice, and you are permitted to disagree with whomever you choose; don't see how I gave the impression that you weren't. Even if you try to hide your response by not `@notifying` ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Fair enough, it's not my answer anymore so I don't expect I'm able to prevent undeletion/deletion/downvotes/upvotes, whatever. But that's not what I'm asking here, I think it'd be nice if I was notified about this change so I might've been able to further improve my answer etc etc.

Comment: @HansPassant +1 for Prime Directive

Comment: The lack of notification is a bit scary. Perhaps the final undelete voter should ping the author. And some info about this could be added to the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: FWIW, I've sometimes temporarily self-deleted when I notice a flaw in my answer (eg it neglects to handle some potentially important corner case) that can't be repaired quickly. I'd hate for my answer to be undeleted by someone who didn't notice the flaw and then some time later I notice that it's undeleted, with a bunch of downvotes by people who _did_ see the flaw. But I guess in that situation I should add a brief explanation to the answer.

Comment: @jpmc26 Sorry, fixed.

Comment: I don't understand, it's okay for the community to undelete an answer deleted by the OP (i.e., making a whole answer exist again) but suggested edits can't "[Deviate] from the original intent of the post." Does the OP "own" the post or not?

Comment: @JasonC No one is forcing anyone to maintain anything. If they deleted their answer and someone else undeleted it, they have every right to a) do nothing, including not responding to comments/edits/etc. or b) ask SO to disassociate their account from the answer. Also, you seem to be missing part of the sentence, namely, *"and, except as otherwise set forth herein, to **allow others to do so** in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You."* but IANAL.

Comment: @JasonC My comment was not to the OP of the question. It was to Rekshino, who was saying "nobody should revive it". Are you saying that the cc-by-sa license doesn't cover whether others can revive it?

Comment: @JasonC Okay, so the license says I could take the answer and post in on my blog (with attribution of course, and assuming I had a blog in working order), but not whether I could undelete the question here on SO... It seems like it would cover whether I could post a separate answer with the exact same content plus attribution, however, but that's a whole different matter. Thanks for the edification. I still think that undeleting an answer doesn't force the answerer to do anything overly burdensome.

Answer (score 37):

Your answer *was* deleted. I even commented to you requesting that you undelete it.

Then, I cast the first un-delete vote. My reasons were simple:

1. Your answer was great! Better than mine, in fact. I thought it would be of use to the OP and to future readers and that, as such, it very much deserves to live;
2. Two answers saying the same thing in different ways, in my opinion, are more valuable than one; your answer is absolutely *not* "useless";
3. It just so happened that I was attempting to upvote it at the exact moment you deleted it;
4. I thought the deletion was a shame;
5. I have the ability and right to cast an un-delete vote.

I don't know who cast the other votes.

As for why you weren't notified, that seems like a bug or missing feature to me.

As for your statement about "a comment asking for a more thorough answer", I don't know whether it means anything, but I satisfied that request within minutes, and actually before you'd posted your answer. ;) Albeit *seconds* before, so there was no deliberate overlap on either of our parts here.

If you don't like your answer being undeleted, I would humbly point you towards the licence you agreed to when posting it, and/or suggest a new [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) for prohibiting undeletion of an answer when it was deleted by that answer's author (though I would likely vote against such a feature overall; perhaps an allowance for author-deletion during the grace period, though?).

You now have a higher score on your answer than I do, and quite right too.
I suggest you just enjoy it! :)

Comment: It was exactly a second before, just a strange coincidence, in my opinion, there was no malice on either side.

Comment: @Lankymart: Certainly. I can't understand why anyone would think an undeletion could be deemed "malice" anyway. It's the opposite! It's a show of support.

Comment: Oh definitely a show of support. I never once thought the undeletion was malice. This question was more about why I didn't get any notifcation when my answer was undeleted by other people, even though 80% of the question is about your answer, but that's just my fault

Comment: @GillBates: Megalols :) Yeah, I think there are some big gaps in notifications overall; I'd definitely like to see delete (10k+) & undelete notifications.

Answer (score 5):

Would you prefer if you could get a notification and then "abandon" the answer? That is, "I deleted this for a reason, I don't want the rep either positive or negative." Everyone could still see that you originally wrote it but maybe it could be a "community answer."

Reason I suggest this:

I could very much see someone writing something they regret, deleting it and then the community reviving the answer because they think it's a good answer, even if you see a fatal flaw (some corner case only an expert could catch.)

Comment: AFAIK you can have a question or answer dis-associated from your account.  It's not a user- accessible feature though; you need to raise a custom moderator flag on the post and put the request in it.